# Why doesnt it save the changes to fields

Tags: python, sql, django, database

I'm trying to change the field values of my objects in my database.
I'm using the following commands[image: the last lines]

I dont know why it isn't saving the changes from false to true.
Please help.
is_approved and is_superuser are attributs of User u.

Thanks

EDIT:
Code for User model

```
class User(AbstractUser):
    TRAINEE = 1
    MENTOR = 2
    MODERATOR = 3
    SUBMENTOR = 4
    USER_TYPES = (
        (TRAINEE, 'Trainee'),
        (MENTOR, 'Industry Expert'),
        (MODERATOR, 'Moderator'),
        (SUBMENTOR,'SubMentor')
    )



    user_type = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(choices=USER_TYPES, null=True, blank=True)
    is_approved = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    has_paid_subscription = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    date_of_birth = models.DateField(null=True, blank=True)
    bio = models.CharField(max_length=2000, validators=[MinLengthValidator(100)], blank=True, null=True)
    profile_picture = models.ImageField(upload_to=profile_media_path, default='default_profile_pic.jpg', blank=True, null=True)
    profile_tags = models.ManyToManyField(Tag, blank=True, related_name='profiles')
    signup_completed = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    referral_code = models.CharField(max_length=100,null=True,blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.username

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(User, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
        if self.bio:
            self.profile_tags.clear()
            lda_model = lda.LDA([self.bio])
            tags = lda_model.generate_tags()
            for tag in tags:
                name = str(tag).capitalize()
                try:
                    tag_object = Tag.objects.get(tag_name=name)
                except Tag.DoesNotExist:
                    tag_object = Tag(tag_name=name)
                    tag_object.save()
                self.profile_tags.add(tag_object)
                tag_object.save()

    @receiver(post_save, sender=settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL)
    def create_auth_token(sender, instance=None, created=False, **kwargs):
        if created:
            Token.objects.create(user=instance)
```

EDIT 2: Tried u[0].refresh_from_db() it didnt work
[image: Last 5 lines]

Comment: Can you post the code of your user model.

Comment: done. Added the code from my models.py file

Comment: Any Help? @kevswanberg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Declare the model you are editing.

```
user = u[0]
user.is_superuser=True
user.save()
```

There is something funky going on with accessing the user from the queryset that is preventing it from saving. Not clear on the details of why but you can get around it by following the above pattern.

Comment: Thanks a lot! This worked for me. But I don't really understand how. If user is a variable of type u[0] and changing its properties to true and saving, how can it affect the real u[0]? isn't like saying :-  int b=10; int a; a=b;a++; cout<<a so a will be 11 but b should stay 10?